# Why is the use of `Span<T>` more expensive than plain array?

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a very complex mathematical algorithm that's been in my code for years. Today, I did some high-level performance tests and found that this algorithm is eating a significant bit of the CPU time. I then saw that (due to its age) the algorithm uses `double[] array = new double[6]` a few times, and then passes the array around to sub-functions. I thought that the use of `Span<double>` and `stackalloc double` should improve performance a bit, as it reduces GC load and possibly some range checks.

I was very surprised that the opposite was the case, and the change caused the overall test time to raise from 23 seconds to 28 seconds. I wrote the following test cases that exhibit the behavior (the actual code is *much* more complicated):

```cs
        // This one must be quite big to see the timing difference for these simple test cases
        private const int MeasuremenLoopCount = 1000000;
        private const int ArraySize = 10;

        [Fact]
        public void UseArray()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < MeasuremenLoopCount; i++)
            {
                double[] array = new double[ArraySize];
                array[0] = 2;

                CalcOnArray(array);
            }
        }

        private void CalcOnArray(double[] array)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                array[i] = array[i - 1] * 2;
            }
        }

        [Fact]
        public void UseSpanOnArray()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < MeasuremenLoopCount; i++)
            {
                Span<double> array = new double[ArraySize];
                array[0] = 2;

                CalcOnSpan(array);
            }
        }

        private void CalcOnSpan(Span<double> array)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                array[i] = array[i - 1] * 2;
            }
        }

        [Fact]
        public void UseSpanOnStack()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < MeasuremenLoopCount; i++)
            {
                StackAllocArray();
            }
        }

        // This method only exists to avoid the "use of stackalloc in a loop" error
        private void StackAllocArray()
        {
            Span<double> array = stackalloc double[ArraySize];
            array[0] = 2;

            CalcOnSpan(array);
        }
```

On my system,

- `UseArray` runs in 46ms,
- `UseSpanOnArray` runs in 57ms
- and `UseSpanOnStack` runs in 55ms.

The (small) difference between the latter two is likely the improvement of using the stack over the heap, but why is `UseArray` significantly faster than `UseSpanOnArray`?

Here are the details of a profiler run, same relation between the test cases, but not much extra insight:
[image: Profiler Result]

Comment: Have you tried to perform benchmarking with [Benchmark.NET](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/overview.html)?

Comment: @PeterCsala I just used the Resharper test runner to measure the times of the different test cases above. Since there's not much code here, I'm not sure I can get more detailed information.

Comment: The idea of `Span<T>` is to avoid making copies of collections. In none of your tests are you making a copy of a collection - and because using indexing in a `Span<T>` is performing an extra level of indirection compared to accessing an array directly, of course it will be slower.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, "_Span<T> is to avoid making copies of collections_" Can you elaborate on that? How is the purpose of Span<T> avoiding making copies of collections? If for example a type only provides some method `Foo(int[] bar)` and you want to pass a sub-section of an existing array, how does Span<T> help you here? Of course the type could offer a `Foo(Span<int> bar)` as well. But for the same reason it could also offer `Foo(int[] bar, int offset, int cout)`, like many types in the BCL already do...

Comment: @PMF You could get information about memory management as well if you would use the [`MemoryDiagnoser`](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/configs/diagnosers.html).

Comment: @PeterCsala I don't care much about the memory usage at this time (it's only a few doubles). It's really the execution time that bothers me.

Comment: @MatthewWatson That could be an answer, if you can somehow source that "`Span<T>` is performing an extra level of indirection compared to accessing an array directly". Because that's just the opposite of what I would have expected.

Comment: @PMF: If you check the [soure for the indexer of `Span<T>`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Span.cs,4877c9ed5c8f8101,references) you can see the code that is getting executed.

Comment: @PMF The implementation of the `Span<T>` indexing operator is `return ref Unsafe.Add(ref _reference, (nint)(uint)index /* force zero-extension */);` (from the link Markus posted above)

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace I suppose I should have said that ONE of the purposes of `Span<T>` is to avoid making copies of collections - of course, it also has the purpose of avoiding GC when being copied (being a `ref struct`). It also allows `ref` access to the elements of the underlying memory block.